# setup a triple integral for an inverted cone

Tags: calculus, integration

I am not sure how to provide a picture, so I will describe the shape as best as possible.

Imagine half a cylinder $(0-\pi)$, whose height is *2* and width is *4* (radius =*2*). Now, imagine the middle is emptied out by a half cone whose pointy tip starts from the bottom and whose base is the same shape as the top of the cylinder (in other words the outer cylinder does not have a top or a roof, if you will)

Now I am to write a triple integral for this shape. I think I figured out the integral of the cone itself using cylindrical coordinates...

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2}f*rdrd\theta dz$$

However this not what I need. This would give me the volume of the cone. I need the *volume of half cylinder* - *volume of half cone*.

How can I change my integral to show this?

**EDIT**

I found a picture that sort of help demonstrate what I mean. Imagine the following shape, except it is cut in half so instead of being $(0-2\pi)$ it is $(0-\pi)$. Also, ignore the sphere.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solid you refer to is the region under the cone and within in cylinder?

For convenience, I will assume that the cone is centered at the origin.

Noting that the top of the cone has the same shape as the cylinder, i.e. a circle of radius $2$ and centered at $0$,

and the height of the cylinder is equal to its radius,

we have the equation of the cone in the positive $z$ axis,

$$z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = r$$

Thus, the volume of the solid is

$$\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}r \text{   } d\theta dr dz$$

Note that $f(z) = 1$ since you are finding the volume of the solid.

Below is a (ugly drawn) picture.

[image]